# Profiling parallel processes with zeromq

Tags: python, profiling, multiprocessing, zeromq

I'm trying to profile an agent-based model. Thus a model where a central class instructs all agents (or a subset) to execute a command, then wait until all are ready and executes the next command… The agents are all different and do not get specific instructions, beyond the command or data from the central entity. Agents interact and trade.

The problem is when I profile the central entity, its time is mainly spend waiting for the agent. If I profile the individual agent, it's time is mainly spend waiting.

Comment: The waiting might be expected. It is even an official slogan of [Powerhose](https://github.com/mozilla-services/powerhose): turn your CPU-bound tasks into I/O-bound tasks so your Python applications are easier to scale.

Comment: @android, yes the waiting is expected, never the less I am missing understanding what is going on. Thanks for drawing my attention to Powerhose.

Answer (score 0):

This explaines how to profile individual processes http://seiferteric.com/?p=277